# getting the following error "pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for SerpAPIWrapper"

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, large-language-model, serpapi

Im getting the following error in vscode but when i run the code in google collab it works fine. looking for some insight into the problem. the keys I replaced for safety reasons but otherwise the code is what I run.

```
from langchain.utilities import SerpAPIWrapper
import openai
import os
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import load_tools, initialize_agent, AgentType
from dotenv import load_dotenv

os.environ["SERPAPI_API_KEY"] = "my key"
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = "my key"

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)

tools = load_tools(["serpapi"], llm=llm)
agent = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True)

agent.run("According to MarketWatch, what is the price of S&P 500 Future Dec 2024?")
```

[the error I'm getting in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EbeI.png)

this is the results of google collab and what im looking for in vscode
[results in google collab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCqkm.png)